# Relationship between $\hat r$, $\hat \theta$ and the $2\times 2$ rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The polar unit basis vector fields are $\hat r(r, \theta) = \cos(\theta)\hat i + \sin(\theta)\hat j$ and $\hat \theta(r, \theta) = -\sin(\theta)\hat i + \cos(\theta)\hat j$.

If I have a vector $\vec x = x^1\hat i + x^2\hat j$, which can be represented with respect to that basis in matrix form as the column matrix $\begin{bmatrix} x^1 \\ x^2 \end{bmatrix}$, then the matrix I use to rotate that vector $\vec x$ by an amount $\theta$ is $$R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$

When I apply this matrix to the column matrix representing $\vec x$ w.r.t. the basis $\{\hat i, \hat j\}$, I get the vector which is $\vec x$ rotated by $\theta$ ALSO W.R.T. the basis $\{\hat i, \hat j\}$.

I can clearly see that the columns of $R$ are just the vector fields $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ w.r.t. $\{\hat i, \hat j\}$.  Is this just a fluke or is there some reason why this should be the case?  Afterall, every part of the matrix equation $\vec x' = R\vec x$ is in the $\{\hat i,\hat j\}$ basis and not the $\{\hat r, \hat \theta\}$ basis.

Is there a similar relationship for $3D$ rotations?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that the $i$th column of a matrix $M$ can be obtained by the product
$Me_i$ where the $i$th coordinate of $e_i$ is $1$, the rest are $0$.

Now, if that matrix represents a linear transformation $R$, in the sense that $R(v)=M\cdot v$ for all vectors $v$, then, by the above obsevration, the $i$th column of $M$ must be $R(e_i)$.

Comment: I understand how to figure out the columns of a matrix if I know how a set of basis vectors are transformed under the associated linear transformation.  I don't know what exactly the relationship is between the $2\times 2$ rotation matrix -- with respect to the $\{\hat i, \hat j\}$ basis -- and the basis vectors $\hat r, \hat \theta$.